# What is the meaning of <script>window["_GOOG_TRANS_EXT_VER"] = "1";</script>

Tags: javascript, header

I have this code on the header of my page

```
    <script>window["_GOOG_TRANS_EXT_VER"] = "1";</script>
```

But i dont  understand its meaning or from where it is generated, anyone knows anything ?
I would like to delete this because it seems to be a problem in the page generation...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you use any Google services on your page?

Comment: it could be an injected script, generated by a browser extension.

Comment: "_GOOG_TRANS" sounds like it should be related to google translate.

Comment: It sounds like *"Google Translation Extended Version"* which makes no sense to me, but you have to give more detail about your page, the usage of scripts, plugins, frameworks, before we can tell you more...

Comment: It's interesting: although it never appears on an official google site, you can find this line of code in many websites! (via google search)

Comment: I have answered below : I have access to this file by FTP but changing it or deleting it doest change anything. The page still loads normally. I would like to modify the script, but my modification are not taken into account online (but works fine in local)

This makes me crazy...

PS : as you can see (http://50.22.181.229/astrowin/right_now/image-big.php) nothing such as google is used, the page is very simple in appearance. I can tell nothing is written in the header such as this  piece of code...

Comment: @Neysor More like *extension version*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is dynamically inserted by the Google Translate extension (or other extensions that were based on the Google Translate extension)

The source code of the Google Translate extension specifically refers to it:

```
/* Copyright 2010 Google */
...
function v(a) {
    var b = {
        noEvents: c,
        content: u('window["_GOOG_TRANS_EXT_VER"] = "1";')
    };
    i.tabs.executeScript(a, {
        code: q(s, b)
    })
}
...
```

and disabling the extension removes it from the page.

Answer (score 2):

Check the actions for your onClick event for in anchor tags, or another JavaScript action that is being fired. it is most likely an escaped quote where there should not be an escape.

Answer (score 0):

All that script does is create a variable, _GOOG_TRANS_EXT_VER, in the global scope which then has a value of 1. If nothing uses this variable it shouldn't generates any issue but it seems like it is inserted by so sort of Google widget.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, the problem is that i cant find from where this code is generated in the source code ? moreover, when i delete/modify the file on the server, the page (in php) is still running like nothing happened. So it seems this short line is a bigger problem and I could not find anything on google...

Comment: Can you post the code for the page? Just to see if anything could be adding that dynamically.

Comment: Its quite a big script that runs.

http://50.22.181.229/astrowin/right_now/image-big.php

Here is the image generated (have a look in the source code)
I have the same file in local but working. I mean if i change something, the modification appears. However, this page seems to be locked O.o

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Google Translate plugin? I saw the same thing and then tried turning my Translate plugin off and this line disappears.

Assuming you are running Chrome, you can check/disable at chrome://extensions/